# Spring cloud sample Eureka server

Tags: spring-cloud

Is there any documentation available related to deploying eureka server on web container like tomcat. I use the spring provided sample and created a war, also renamed it to 'eureka.war' but the dashboard is not displayed..

The code works fine with spring boot but looks some configuration is required for deploying it as war.

Comment: Any errors or configuration you could share?

Answer (score 3):

See this commit: https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/eureka/commit/1de7c89cf3f79e4707dbabe91ea60eb06f2268aa

In pom.xml

```
<packaging>war</packaging>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

In EurekaApplication.java

```
public class EurekaApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer { /*...*/ }
```

Comment: There's a generic guide here as well: https://spring.io/guides/gs/convert-jar-to-war/